# Does aqueous ammonium fluoride solution release hydrogen fluoride vapors?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, vapor-pressure

Can $\ce{HF}$ vapors be released from $\ce{NH4F}$ solution in water $(w(\ce{NH4F}) = 40\,\%)$ at room temperature?

I assume that dissolving $\ce{NH4F}$ in water produces small amount of $\ce{HF}.$

Comment: The question is not "Can ?" but "How much ?". There will be equilibrium F-(aq)<=>HF2-(aq)<=>HF(aq)<=>HF-(g) But as the solution would be slightly alkalic, I expect the partial HF(g) pressure as negligibly low. It would be higher for NH4HF2 or an acidized solution.

Comment: Also, it sublimes when heated to give ammonia and HF. The reaction is reversible.